# Pro*C/SQL Prepare Satement not recognizing host variable in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, proc

I'm trying to drop an arbitrary table in Pro*C using the SQL API. However Oracle fails to recognize the host variable:

```
char sqlcode[1024];
char table[10];
printf("Enter the table name: ");
scanf("%s", table);  // Store table name

strcpy(sqlcode, "drop table :table"); // Create sql statement
exec sql prepare dropTable from :sqlcode;
exec sql execute dropTable using :table;
```

Results in an error:

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

What's going on here? And yes, assume the table exists.

Comment: Is the table name really 10 characters long? Provide test data please.

Comment: It's not. I doubt however that is the issue.

Comment: So if the table name is > 10 characters, how do you expect the char tablep[10] array to hold the whole name? I don't say it's not possible, in Oracle 11g for instance table names can be up to 30 characters.